# How do I put a element n times in a list without using the replicate or repeat function?

Tags: haskell

I have a function rep which requires a list with `int`s. My task now is to put each of these numbers in separate lists with n times the number. For example 
`[1,3,5]` to `[[1],[3,3,3],[5,5,5,5,5]]` So far I can put each int in a separate list but I don't really now how to put them n times in the list without using replicate or repeat.

This is the code I have so far:

```
rep [] = []
rep (x1:xs) = [[x1]] ++ (rep xs)
```

Comment: well I guess your first task is to re-implement `replicate` ;)

Comment: btw: `[a] ++ as == a:as`

Comment: are you allowed to use list comprehensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution without `repeat` or `replicate`:

```
rep = map (\ n -> foldr (const (n :)) [] [1..n])
```

Answer (score 3):

As this is a homework/learning exercise - just want to give some hints

Split the task in two parts a function

- `myReplicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` which replicates a single element as many times as the `Int` tells it to.

  ```
  myReplicate n x | n > 0 = ...
                  | n == 0 = ...
                  | n < 0 = error "Error myReplicate: no negative arguments allowed"
  ```
- a second function `myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` that applies a function to every element of a given list.

  ```
  myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
  myMap f [] = []
  myMap f (x:xs) = ...
  ```

then `rep = myMap (\x -> myReplicate x x)`